# Logic for sending emails to particular User in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

This is more like a conceptual question because I have the feeling that I am doing this wrong:

I have to send emails to some Users that satisfy some conditions.  What I have right now is the following:

1) A task that basically does this:

```
users = User.includes(:aptitudes).where({:role => ['Boy','boy','kid'], :aptitudes => {:name =>'Good'} })
users.each do |user|
  MyMailer.report(user).deliver
end
```

2) In the report method of MyMailer, I have several things:

```
def report(user)

    @user = user
    @value = @user.value

    @travels = @user.travels.where(:end_at)

    @rewards = @user.rewards

    # More logic depending of values of User.

...

end
```

What happens is that in the Mailer itself sometimes a particular property or attribute of the object @user does not satisfy for the email to be sent.  I am wondering where am I supposed to make sure that all the Users that I pass to the Mailers will be sent an email ? Shall I create a new method in the rake to do those checkings? Or how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can do as you wish as long as the name is revealing enough of the intentions.

If you gave me this MyMailer object to use, without knowing the implementation, I would expect it to send a `report` when requested and not filter out of its own whim... eventually deal with other problems (fail to send, delays, retries etc.) but when I give it a user I **want** that user to be emailed.

So, to answer your question, yes I would either filter out all the users before calling the Mailer, or define a method in the Mailer called something like `report_only_those_users` that will take care of the filtering.

By the way, you can pass a list of emails to [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) (section 2.3.4), without having to loop and send one at a time.

Comment: Each email has particular data to be send...Not all the emails are the same :) - My question is, where should I do the filtering? Create a method in the task itself?

Comment: Yeah in that case I would do that. Filter the users before and let the Mailer take care of the body-content.